# Angular : Can ng-options (bound to ng-model ( db table) ) allow input and/or edit of an option, if so how please

Tags: angularjs, input, ng-options

I'm hoping angularjs ng-options can allow a user to enter a new value / option or edit an existing one in-situ
Is this possible? or is there a way to do so?

My code:

```
<div class="col-md-2">
        <select class="form-control"
            ng-model="BatchNos.Selected"
            ng-options="item.BatchNo for item in BatchNos track by item.BatchId"
            style="background-color:dimgray;font-weight:Bold;color:white">
       </select>
    </div>
```

Comment: No, a select can't do that. You'd need a custom widget.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can add an option textbox inside it and input type submit and finally when clicked on submit, you can add the item to the BatchNos